# .NET 6 Power BI embed on Existing application

Tags: c#, .net, powerbi, azure-active-directory

I have an existing application where I would like to have Power BI embeds integrated. I followed along with adding everything [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-customer-app) but I am receiving a 403 (forbidden) error whenever the code hits

`var report = await pbiClient.Reports.GetReportInGroupAsync(WorkspaceId, ReportId);`

This is my appsettings.json

```
"AzureAd": {
    "AuthenticationMode": "ServicePrincipal",
    "AuthorityUri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Scope": [ "https://analysis.usgovcloudapi.net/powerbi/api/.default" ],
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxxxxxx.gov/",
    "ClientSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc"
  },
  "PowerBi": {
    "ServiceRootUrl": "https://api.powerbigov.us/"
  },
```

This is what I have added to my Program.cs file

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(PowerBiServiceApi));

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

I do have a "PowerBiServiceApi.cs" file as per the Microsoft guide, only change is this:
`public const string powerbiApiDefaultScope = "https://analysis.usgovcloudapi.net/powerbi/api/.default";`

Then, lastly, over to my Controller I have:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LagAnalysis()
        {
            
            Guid workspaceID = new Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");
            Guid reportID = new Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");
            var viewModel = await powerBIServiceApi.GetReport(workspaceID, reportID);
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

The Service Principal Account has been added as an admin to the Power BI workspace and has all permissions granted.

EDIT:
These are the following errors I am receiving:
1.
Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition: Information: False MSAL 4.55.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19044
NOTE: For this error, it does say "=== Token Acquisition finished successfully:"

2.
Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

3.
System.InvalidOperationException: The exception handler configured on ExceptionHandlerOptions produced a 404 status response.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/troubleshoot/